# Left align menu icon

Tags: css, menu, alignment

Im trying to left align a menu icon.

The icon is displaying above the menu name but I would like to align in to the left of the menu name.

The CSS I have is:

```
.icon_name_here:before {
content: '';
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
background: url('http://url_of_icon_here.com') no-repeat left;}
```

How / what do I have to do to align the icon to the left of the menu name?

Comment: Try to use the line-height rule

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Comment: @zkanoca [link](http://www.coffeeonline.co.za)

Answer (score 1):

Without posting a relevant code its hard to give a exact answer. I've tried to re-build on the assumption of the CSS you posted and here I've build a demo. See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ruquhive/1/edit)** .

**CSS is like this.**

```
ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul li {padding:4px;}

.icon_name_here:before {
content: '';
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
display: block;
float: left;
padding:4px;
background: url('http://lorempixel.com/24/24/') no-repeat 0 0;}
```

**HTML is like it.**

```
 <ul>
    <li class="icon_name_here">Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>
```

**Updates**

you have to add a `display:inline-block` on `<a>` tag. Check the uploaded image.[image]

```
<a href="coffeeonline.co.za"; style="display:inline-block">HOME</a>
```

Comment: thanks, please see [link](http://www.coffeeonline.co.za) for the example for what I am referring to. Many thanks

Comment: you are adding `display:inline-block` on pseudo element. Also inside `li` there is an `a` tag you have to give them `display:inline-block`. Like this <a href="http://www.coffeeonline.co.za" style="display:inline-block">HOME</a>

Comment: just put that piece of line in any css file and that would work then.

Comment: bear in mind you should be more specific while posting this line of code. otherwise all `<a>` tag will be effected. so you can try like apply `li.coffeeonline_bean_icon a{display:inline-block};`

Answer (score 0):

use display: inline style for both image and  Text

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method like a variant. It can be helpfull when you want to use sprites

**HTML**

```
<div class="your-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, beatae consequatur dolore doloribus dolorum harum, laboriosam magnam natus, numquam odit officiis quia quisquam suscipit tempora voluptatum. Facere quae quis sed?
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.your-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px; /*space between block edge and displaying of your text*/
}
.your-content:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; /*position of your icon*/
    left: 0px; /*position of your icon*/
    width: px; /*width of your icon*/
    height: px; /*height of your icon*/
    background: url(img/your-icon-bg.png)  no-repeat;
}
```